# Asp classic open another record in case

Tags: asp-classic

I want to display all these records if Case 7 is selected, but i dont know how to open specefied records in asp classic, is it possible?

```
    ELSE IF @Case = 7 BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_AutoWorkshop WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Expert WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Samsung WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_SonyCIC WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Whitegoods WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    END
```

This is the html + asp i can display the first record from dbo.tbl_PostalCode

```
                <tr> 
                                  <td class="blackb">RecId</td>
                                    <td class="blackb">Country</td>
                                    <td class="blackb">PostalCode</td>
                                    <td class="blackb">Town</td>
                                    <td class="blackb">Lat</td>
                                    <td class="blackb">Lng</td>
                </tr>


                                                    <%
                                If Not RSOrder.EOF then
                                    Do Until RSOrder.EOF
                                %>
                                <tr>    
                                    <td><%=RSOrder("Rec_ID")%> </td>
                                        <td><%=RSOrder("Country")%></td>
                                        <td><%=RSOrder("PostalCode")%>  </td>
                                        <td><%=RSOrder("Town")%> </td>
                                        <td><%=RSOrder("Lat")%></td>
                                        <td><%=RSOrder("Lng")%></td>
                                </tr>


                                    <% 
                                        RSOrder.MoveNext
                                    Loop
                                Else%>




                                <%End If %>
                                <%End if%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet is to make your SQL return one resultset instead of 6, make a change like this:

```
ELSE IF @Case = 7 
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_AutoWorkshop WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Expert WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Samsung WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_SonyCIC WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.tbl_PostalCode_Whitegoods WHERE (PostalCode = @PostalCode)
END
```

This way when you loop thru your recordset - a single loop will yield all results

As an alternative, if you need to keep your current SQL that returns multiple results, use Recodset's [NextRecordset](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_nextrecordset.asp) method, it allows you to create an outer loop that loops thru returned results (inner loop will still be your current one that loops thru individual records)

In your case it would be something like

```vbs
Do Until RSOrder is Nothing

   Do Until RSOrder.EOF

      'Using function from http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42275 to see if specific field exists
      If FieldExistsInRS(RSOrder, "MyColumn")
         'do something specific for this result
      End If

      RSOrder.MoveNext
   Loop

   'Get result from the next SELECT
   Set RSOrder = RSOrder.NextRecordset 

Loop
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, not every table has the same information its just PostalCode and Country that are the same. so UNION is out of the question

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson added alternative solution, but since you're *displaying* the same information, perhaps instead of doning `SELECT *`, you can do `SELECT [just the common columns]` and in this case UNION will work

Comment: Yeah, i do know that. But i want to display everything since its all important.

Comment: Then the `NextRecordset` id what you're looking for

Comment: Could you try to be more specefic on where the NextRecordset should be i'd be grateful :)

Comment: @PatrikChristoffersson Take a look at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677569(v=vs.85).aspx it uses several SELECT statements as datasource, just as your case, then in outer loop loops thru results, while in inner loop loops thru records of a result

Comment: I still don't get it, im sorry :)

Comment: Updated the answer with modification to your code. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that helped a bit. How can i modify that code so i can have diffrent outputs on diffrent cases?

Comment: You mean different SELECTs? This whole case applies to `@Case = 7` ?

Comment: Well, Each tabel have 3 common rows RecId,Country,PostalCode. 

And some tables have important rows that i need to display.

Comment: Since, like you said each result has some unique columns that other results don't you can use function `FieldExistsInRS`described here http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42275 and based on field existence run code,  specific to that result (updated my code example)

Comment: Thanks for your time, althought it helped me quite, It still did not satisfy my need. I want to have diffrent texts for diffrent select statements - running in order from the first one located at the top of the Case to the last one.

Comment: Like this. 

Rec id country postalcode  dbo.tbl_postalcode
1    1  1        1         
Rec id country postalcode etc etc dbo.tbl_postalcode_autoworkshop
1    1   1       1         92  32

etc